# Converting from one class to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am calling a webservice that returns an array of one of four custom classes. 
All classes have the same inner contents - one string named Description, and another string named Value.
I am trying to write a single method that can accept any of the four classes, and put its contents into a dropdown list's datasource.

Is there a way to convert from an unknown composite class to a specified class with the same contents? Or strip the contents out?

Or will I have to write four identical functions with different datatypes?

*edit: added code*

```
    myDropDown.DataSource = CreateDataSource(myWebServiceResponse.Items);
    myDropDown.DataTextField = "DescriptionField";
    myDropDown.DataValueField = "ValueField";

    // Bind the data to the control.
    myDropDown.DataBind();
```

...

```
    public ICollection CreateDataSource(MasterData[] colData)
    {
        // Create a table to store data for the DropDownList control.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Define the columns of the table.
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DescriptionField", typeof(String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ValueField", typeof(String)));

        // Populate the table
        foreach (sapMasterData objItem in colData)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(CreateRow(objItem, dt));
        }

        // Create a DataView from the DataTable to act as the data source 
        // for the DropDownList control.
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        return dv;
    }

    DataRow CreateRow(MasterData objDataItem, DataTable dt)
    {
        // Create a DataRow using the DataTable defined in the  
        // CreateDataSource method.
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr[0] = objDataItem.Description;
        dr[1] = objDataItem.Value;

        return dr;
    }

public class MasterData
{
    public string Value;
    public string Description;
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide some codes.

Comment: You can use `dynamic`.

Comment: You could put an interface on all the classes and work with that. Or you could use AutoMapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) control requires you an `IEnumerable` as DataSource and then you could specify the [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) and [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx):

```
dropDownList.DataSource = some_Array_You_Retrieved_From_Your_Web_Service;
dropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
dropDownList.DataTextField = "Description";
dropDownList.DataBind();
```

As you can see it doesn't really matter the actual type of the array, as long as it has `Value` and `Description` properties to bind it to.

Answer (score 1):

A wrapper would do, you have two approaches:

```
public class WSData
{
    public string Value;
    public string Description;

    // First approach: single ctor with dynamic parameter
    public WSData(dynamic source)
    {
        this.Value = source.Value;
        this.Description = source.Description;
    }

    // ----- or --------

    // Second approach: one ctor for each class
    public WSData(FirstTypeFromWS source)
    {
        this.Value = source.Value;
        this.Description = source.Description;
    }
    public WSData(SecondTypeFromWS source)
    {
        this.Value = source.Value;
        this.Description = source.Description;
    }
}
```

usage is the same:

```
WSData yourData = new WSData(data_retrieved_from_service);
// now, bind the WSData object: you have abstracted yourself from
// the service and as a bonus your code can be attached elsewhere more easily
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an interface that it is implemented by all four classes (e.g. IDescriptionValue) and write a method that accepts a parameter of that type, for instance:

```
public interface IDescriptionValue
{
public string Description {get;set;}
public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class CustomClass1 : IDescriptionValue{
public string Description {get;set;}
public string Value {get;set;}
}
//snip...
public class CustomClass4 : IDescriptionValue{
public string Description {get;set;}
public string Value {get;set;}
}
//accepts parameters of type IDescriptionValue
public void setDropdownData(IDescriptionValue inputData){
// your code here
}
```

Comment: The four classes are defined by the web service (which was not written by me). I don't want to change the class definitions in case I need to refresh the service reference, because then I'd lose my modifications.